# Difference between wcf and web api uri definition

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, wcf-rest

I want to convert our existing `WCF REST` web services to `ASP.NET Web API`so I started to look into it.

Getting one of my function (i.e. login) up and running in `ASP.NET Web API` was quite straight forward but there is one thing I'm confused about and I hope one of you can clarify this for me.

In our `WCF REST` web service, our login (POST) function was called as follows:

`http://localhost/mywebsite/mywebservice.svc/Authentication/Login`

We'd pass a `LoginRequest` to it and we'd get a `LoginResponse` back.

Now in `ASP.NET Web API`, I've our Login (POST) function is being called as follows:

`http://localhost/api/authentication` and I'm passing the same `LoginRequest` and I get the same `LoginResponse`.

My confusion is, how does `ASP.NET Web API` know to use the Login function which is defined in the `AuthenticationController`?

I assume it has something to do with the parameter type being passed but what if I have another function that has the same parameter type, how would it differentiate between the 2?

For example, what if I had a `LocalLogin` and `CloudLogin` (not the case btw) and both require the `LoginRequest` as an input parameter and both return the `LoginResponse`, how would it know which one to call since it's not part of the URI?

Thanks.

Comment: How URL's get matched to a particular method is called "Routing". Perhaps you should look up "ASP.NET Web API Routing"

Comment: This link may help you: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/aspnet-web-api-vs-windows-communication-foundation-wcf.